# I need to use Linux for a few days. Any free service on internet?

Tags: linux, service, virtual-machine, shared

I was wondering if there is such service, either free or very cheap, where I can use a Linux machine for a few days to install and run 2 programs on it. Really all I need is to debug my ANSI C application with Valgrind debugger which only runs on Linux and I don't have access to it right now for various reasons.

So all I need is this:

1. being able to compile/install valgrind and my prog with gcc
2. run valgrind and my prog
3. ftp/sftp, or any other method as long I can send or download the files on machine

I thought of doing it over sourceforge but my software is not anything useful to humanity, it is for a scientific research, doing some math calculations...

Maybe anyone of you know of such service? 
Or knows where I can use a Linux machine once in a while?

Please let me know
thanks
maxim

Comment: Is a virtual machine an option?

Comment: Or how about I liveCD or USB stick?

Comment: Or a fresh harddisk (or partition)

Comment: So sad to admit, but unfortunately I cannot download anything bigger than some 20-30mb right now. Either Virtual Machine or a livecd/usb stick would require me large downloads and I am sitting on a paid and slow internet connection through a phone... Even youtube is a luxury for me right now. Hopefully in few days I get connected, but not before monday... So I need a quick solution for now...

Comment: Open a demo account at http://theqvd.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up an Ubuntu micro instance for free on Amazon's infrastructure: http://aws.amazon.com/free/

But really, I would rather recommend you installing Linux on your own, you can even do it on a USB memory stick (pendrive).

Comment: allright.... going to check amazon now. As of my own Linux, yeah, I have one, at home.... 400km away :))))

Comment: @user1885558 Cool! Let it be a beginning of a great adventure for you :)

Comment: @user1885558 Note that installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox running in Windows just takes about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS micro instances are free for I think a year. Question is whether they are sufficient enough to do what you want, though besides that if you only need a few days perhaps the hourly paid instances are also cheap enough.

Another option would be to run a LiveCD in either a VM or physical machine and do it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Windows, you can download VMware Player for free.

http://www.vmware.com/products/player/

Then download whatever Linux distro ISO image you'd like to use and open it in VMware Player.  It will run like you installed Linux on your machine.

If you're using a Mac, I'm out of my element but I think someone told me before Macs run on top of Linux so I think you can open a terminal and run/test/develop your program.

Comment: Macs don't run on top of Linux...